# Upper bound on the sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Let $0\leq x\leq i\leq y\leq n$, where $n \in N$. Find an upper bound of the sum
$$
\sum_{i=x}^y{i+x-1 \choose x-1}{n+y-i \choose y-i}
$$